# How do I sort hash based on frequency of occurrences in Ruby? Is there a better way than what I have?

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash, hashmap, find-occurrences

I am trying to write a method that takes in a string and outputs the number of occurrences a character shows up in a Hash in descending order.

I can do this for each of the words. I need to do this for each of the character.

```
string = "Apple, Banana, Time, Time, Time, Banana Apple, Time."

def cw(string)
  w = string.gsub(/\W/," ").split
  freq = 
  Hash[w.group_by { |x| x }.map { |k, vs| [k, vs.length] }.sort_by { |k, length| -length }]
   return freq
 end
 puts cw(string)
```

Expecting: A => 8; B => 2; ..etc.

Actual:  {"Time"=>4, "Apple"=>2, "Banana"=>2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are splitting by an empty string:

```
w = string.gsub(/\W/," ").split("")
```

Comment: Opps, its giving me a count for white (blank space). Nope, wait. Fixed it. I went back and reduced space in .gsub(/\W/,"  ") to (/\W/,"") and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You could replace `split('')` with `chars` or, better, `each_char`, which returns an enumerator..

Answer (score 0):

I assume the count of each letter is case-independent.

```
str = "Apple, Banana, Time, Time, Time, Banana Apple, Time."
```

You said you to sort by "the number of occurrences a character" (not a "letter", for example). You could do that as follows.

```
h = str.downcase.
        each_char.
        each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }.
        sort_by { |_,v| -v }.
        to_h
  #=> {"a"=>8, " "=>7, "e"=>6, ","=>6, "i"=>4, "t"=>4, "m"=>4, "p"=>4,
  #    "n"=>4, "b"=>2, "l"=>2, "."=>1}
```

If only the counts of letters is desired there is one more step:

```
h.select { |k,_| k.match?(/[a-z]/i) } 
  #=> {"a"=>8, "e"=>6, "i"=>4, "t"=>4, "m"=>4, "p"=>4, "n"=>4, "b"=>2, "l"=>2}
```

This last step could of course be chained to the calculation of `h` above.

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.downcase
  #=> "apple, banana, time, time, time, banana apple, time."
b = a.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "apple, banana, time, time, time, banana apple,
  #                  time.":each_char>
```

We can see the elements the enumerator `c` will generate and pass to the block by converting it to an array.

```
b.to_a
  #=> ["a", "p", "p", "l", "e", ",", " ", "b", "a", "n", "a", "n",
  #    "a", ",", " ", "t", "i", "m", "e", ",", " ", "t", "i", "m",
  #    "e", ",", " ", "t", "i", "m", "e", ",", " ", "b", "a", "n",
  #    "a", "n", "a", " ", "a", "p", "p", "l", "e", ",", " ", "t",
  #    "i", "m", "e", "."]
```

Continuing,

```
c = b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"a"=>8, "p"=>4, "l"=>2, "e"=>6, ","=>6, " "=>7, "b"=>2,
  #    "n"=>4, "t"=>4, "i"=>4, "m"=>4, "."=>1}
d = c.sort_by { |_,v| -v }
  #=> [["a", 8], [" ", 7], ["e", 6], [",", 6], ["i", 4], ["t", 4],
  #    ["m", 4], ["p", 4], ["n", 4], ["b", 2], ["l", 2], [".", 1]]
e = d.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>8, " "=>7, "e"=>6, ","=>6, "i"=>4, "t"=>4, "m"=>4,
  #    "p"=>4, "n"=>4, "b"=>2, "l"=>2, "."=>1}
e.select { |k,_| k.match?(/[a-z]/i) }
  #=> {"a"=>8, "e"=>6, "i"=>4, "t"=>4, "m"=>4, "p"=>4, "n"=>4,
  #    "b"=>2, "l"=>2}
```

The last step can be omitted if the calculation of `a` were changed to the following.

```
a = str.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, '')
  #=> "applebananatimetimetimebananaappletime
```

Comment: This really helps me understand well. Thanks! I am still a newbie and use terms too liberally (i.e. 'character' vs 'letter'). But working on this to be more cautious.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gsub in below fashion.

```
string = "Apple, Banana, Time, Time, Time, Banana Apple, Time."

def cw(string)
  a = string.gsub(/[aA]/).count
  b = string.gsub(/[bB]/).count
  Hash['A', a, 'B', b]
end

cw(string)
  => {"A"=>8, "B"=>2}
```